# Compounding needs to be calculating from previous row and inserted at current row in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

There is a dataset where I have grouped it at Loan and Row level, and having a base value populated for Row =1 .
Need to calculate compounding value and create a new column "Compounding_new_value" where
Condition :

1. If Base_val is not 0, it will insert Base_val to Compounding_new_value as it is,
2. Next row, when base_val is 0,  first time it needs to calculate compounding value with the formula (Base_value from Previous row + (Base_val from Previous row * Interest value from Current Row) and then insert this value to "Compounding_new_value" column
3. Next row, when base_val is 0 , it will calculate compounding value with formula (Compounding_new_value from Previous row + (Compounding_new_value from Previous row * Interest value from Current Row) and insert the value to Compounding_new_value which will become input for next row until it hits Base_val as non-zero and start processing as from step 1.

Issue: It is updating Compounding_new_value only for first row, but not updating for remaining row.

Sample Code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

simpleData = (
    (1, "123", 2, 3000),
    (2, "123", 2, 0),
    (3, "123", 2, 0),
    (4, "123", 2, 0),
    (5, "123", 2, 0),
    (6, "123", 2, 0),
    (1, "234", 3, 2000),
    (2, "234", 3, 0),
    (3, "234", 3, 0),
    (4, "234", 3, 0),
)

columns = ["Row", "Loan", "Interest", "Base_val"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=simpleData, schema=columns)
# Adding a column Compound_new_value having default 0 value
df = df.withColumn("Compound_new_value", F.lit(0))
```

[image: How data looks like]

```py
WindowSpec = Window.partitionBy("loan").orderBy(F.col("loan").asc(), F.col("Row").asc())
df = df.withColumn(
    "Compound_new_value",
    F.when(
        F.col("Base_val") == 0,
        F.lag(
            F.col("Compound_new_value", 1).over(WindowSpec)
            + (
                F.lag(F.col("Compound_new_value"), 1).over(WindowSpec)
                * F.col("Interest")
            )
        ).otherwise(F.col("Base_val")),
    ),
)

df.show(10, False)
```

[image: After executing dataframe]

Ideally, Compounding_new_value should be updated for all rows, but it is happening for first row only. When I reexecute the below dataframe, then only updates Compounding_new_value for next row. Basically, it needs to be update for all rows in one go.

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "Compound_new_value",
    F.when(
        F.col("Base_val") == 0,
        F.lag(
            F.col("Compound_new_value", 1).over(WindowSpec)
            + (
                F.lag(F.col("Compound_new_value"), 1).over(WindowSpec)
                * F.col("Interest")
            )
        ).otherwise(F.col("Base_val")),
    ),
)

df.show(10, False)
```

[image: After reexecuting the dataframe it updates for second row]

After re-executing the dataframe it updates for second row.

Please help, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is `Interest` the same for a `Loan` ? Or 1 `loan` can have differents `interest` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who have responded to the question .. really appreciate the efforts.
I have been able to solve it. It is working as expected and tested on real data as well for more than 1m records and performance wise it took less than 5 minutes. Answering it here, so it can be useful for others if required.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import math

def calculateCompounding(Int_rate,Base_val):
    Int_rate = float(Int_rate)
    Base_val = float(Base_val)
    return Base_val + (Base_val * Int_rate)

def getCols(seq_si_factors):
    Row=0
    Interest=0
    Base_val=0
    compounded_val=0
    stmt=''
    for i, delta in enumerate(seq_si_factors.split(',')):
        if i ==0:
            Row, Interest, Base_val = delta.split(';')
            compounded_val = calculateCompounding(Interest,Base_val)
            compounded_val = math.ceil(compounded_val * 100 ) * 0.01
        else:
            Row, Interest, Base_val = delta.split(';')
            compounded_val = calculateCompounding(Interest,compounded_val)
            compounded_val = math.ceil(compounded_val * 100 ) * 0.01
        stmt = stmt + str(Row) + ':' + str(Interest) + ':' + str(compounded_val) + ':' + '#'
    return stmt




simpleData = ((1, ”123” ,0.413424657 ,5.43), \
    ((2”, “123” ,0.4272054789 ,0.0), \
    ((3, ”123” ,0.2 ,0.0), \
    ((4, ”123” ,0.2 ,0.0), \
    ((5, ”123” ,0.2 ,0.0), \
    ((6, ”123” ,0.2 ,0.0), \
    ((1, ”234” ,0.3 ,12.1), \
    ((2, ”234” ,0.3 ,0.0), \
    ((3, ”234” ,0.3 ,0.0), \
    ((4, ”234” ,0.3 ,0.0), \
)

columns = [ “Row”, “Loan”, “Interest”, “Base_val”]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
df.show(10,False)
```

[image: data set]

```
WindowSpec = Window.partitionBy('loan').orderBy(F.col('Row').asc())
WindowSpec2 = Window.partitionBy('loan').orderBy(F.col('Row').desc())

df2=df.withColumn('col',F.concat(F.col('Row'),F.lit(';'),F.col('Interest'),F.lit(';'),F.col('Base_val'))).withColumn('all_step',F.collect_list('col').over(WindowSpec))
df2=df2.withColumn('rseq',F.row_number().over(WindowSpec2)).filter(F.col('rseq')==1)
df2=df2.withColumn('all_step', F.concat_ws(',', df2.all_step))
spark.udf.register('f_compounding',getCols)

stmt="""
    SELECT 
        b.loan
        ,f_compounding(b.all_step) as combined_cols
    FROM df b
    """

df3 = spark.sql(stmt)
df4 = df3.withColumn('cols', F.explode(F.split('combined_cols','#'))).where('cols != ""')
df4 = df4.withColumn("splitcol",F.split(F.col("cols"),":")).select('loan', F.col("splitcol").getItem(0).alias('Row'), F.col("splitcol").getItem(1).alias('Interest'),)F.col("splitcol").getItem(1).alias('CompoundedValue')
df4.withColumn("CompoundedValue", df4['CompoundedValue'].cast(Decimal(9,2)))
df4.show(10,False)
```

[image: Compounded values]

Answer (score 0):

**This solution works if `interest` is constant for a loan.**

You need to do some **highschool** math to solve this :

**Vi** is the compound_value at level **i**.
**I** is the interest.
Then, Vi+1 = Vi + I*Vi = Vi * (1+I)
Then, **Vi+1 = V0 * (1+I)^(i-1)**

You just need to apply this formula at your dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df.withColumn(
    "compound_value",
    F.first("Base_val").over(W.partitionBy("Loan").orderBy("Row"))
    * F.pow(1 + F.col("Interest"), F.col("row") - 1),
).show()

+---+----+--------+--------+--------------+                                     
|Row|Loan|Interest|Base_val|compound_value|
+---+----+--------+--------+--------------+
|  1| 234|       3|    2000|        2000.0|
|  2| 234|       3|       0|        8000.0|
|  3| 234|       3|       0|       32000.0|
|  4| 234|       3|       0|      128000.0|
|  1| 123|       2|    3000|        3000.0|
|  2| 123|       2|       0|        9000.0|
|  3| 123|       2|       0|       27000.0|
|  4| 123|       2|       0|       81000.0|
|  5| 123|       2|       0|      243000.0|
|  6| 123|       2|       0|      729000.0|
+---+----+--------+--------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` to multiply sequentially the interest rate with the previous amounts for `Compound_new_value`.
This solution works even if the interest rate is not constant across a loan because the values inserted in `list` would be different.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window\
  .partitionBy('Loan')\
  .orderBy('Row')\
  .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

df = df\
  .withColumn('values', F.when(F.col('Base_val') == 0, F.lit(1 + F.col('Interest')/100))\
                         .otherwise(F.col('Base_val')))\
  .withColumn('list', F.collect_list('values').over(w))\
  .withColumn('Compound_new_value', F.expr('aggregate(list, cast(1 as double), (acc, x) -> acc * x)'))

  df.show()

+---+----+--------+--------+------+--------------------------------------+------------------+
|Row|Loan|Interest|Base_val|values|list                                  |Compound_new_value|
+---+----+--------+--------+------+--------------------------------------+------------------+
|1  |123 |2       |3000    |3000.0|[3000.0]                              |3000.0            |
|2  |123 |2       |0       |1.02  |[3000.0, 1.02]                        |3060.0            |
|3  |123 |2       |0       |1.02  |[3000.0, 1.02, 1.02]                  |3121.2000000000003|
|4  |123 |2       |0       |1.02  |[3000.0, 1.02, 1.02, 1.02]            |3183.6240000000003|
|5  |123 |2       |0       |1.02  |[3000.0, 1.02, 1.02, 1.02, 1.02]      |3247.2964800000004|
|6  |123 |2       |0       |1.02  |[3000.0, 1.02, 1.02, 1.02, 1.02, 1.02]|3312.2424096000004|
|1  |234 |3       |2000    |2000.0|[2000.0]                              |2000.0            |
|2  |234 |3       |0       |1.03  |[2000.0, 1.03]                        |2060.0            |
|3  |234 |3       |0       |1.03  |[2000.0, 1.03, 1.03]                  |2121.8            |
|4  |234 |3       |0       |1.03  |[2000.0, 1.03, 1.03, 1.03]            |2185.454          |
+---+----+--------+--------+------+--------------------------------------+------------------+
```

You can of course drop the temporary columns `values` and `list` if you don't need them.

*Note: I assumed that your `Interest` column was a percentage, therefore I divided it by 100.*